# Get a single result from ordered results?

Tags: mysql

Okay, so I have two tables. The first is a table of events. The second is a table of occurring time-stamps of said events. An event can have multiple occurrences, so I could have 5 rows in the events table, with 40 rows in the occurs table.

What I am trying to do is simply get the full list of events, linked with the next occurrence of that events. The problem I am having is getting the next occurrence. Theoretically, I could be using a `GROUP BY`, but the problem is that grouping happens before ordering. so it wont get the next occurrence, but simply the next matching row.

```
SELECT occurs.*, events.*
FROM occurs
    INNER JOIN events ON (events.event_id = occurs.event_id)
WHERE occurs.occur_start >= 1441068400
ORDER BY occurs.occur_start ASC
```

Using the above code will return 40 rows in occurrence order. How can I modify the above code to only get 5 rows, grouped by event_ids?

Comment: If you want stuff grouped by `event_id`s, may be one thing to try is adding a `GROUP BY event_id`?

Comment: @mustaccio as he said he needs `group by` to work after `order by`

Comment: The question was: "How can I modify the above code to only get 5 rows, grouped by event_ids?", wasn't it. "The full list of events", as stated earlier in the text, does not depend at all on occurrences, so I'm not even sure what is the reason for a join. On the other hand, the query itself wants both events and occurrences. If the OP could provide some sample data and the expected output, the answer, I'm sure, would be easier to derive.

Comment: there's an http://sqlfiddle.com for this purpose but I can't think of anything than subqueries for this, not sure if that's what you want